# wicked_pdf: Is it possible to have the header only show on the first page & the footer only on the last?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

Right now I have `:header => {:html => {:template => "layouts/pdf_header.html.erb"}}` setting things up.  Is there something I can pass in that will only show the header on the first page of the document?

Can I do this for the footer as well? It's almost more important here, because I can't really think of any other way to get a footer to dynamically stick to the bottom of the page when it's going to be different lengths and different numbers of pages every time.

Comment: Maybe if you give no header but do a `render :partial => '/path/to/my/header'` on the first page?

Comment: @MrYoshiji I realize I can do that, but am hoping to not have to include header & footer partials on every page that will be rendered to pdf. I also use the views for other things besides pdf's, so don't want to have to stick logic in there as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some quick javascript can take care of this. Follow the boilerplate laid out under 'Footers And Headers' on [wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/README_WKHTMLTOPDF)

These are your header and footer templates respectively.
The key variable to keep track of is 'page' which is available from URL hash.
Your header will look something like this:

```
<div class="headerContent" style="display:none">
   ...my awesome html
    <hr />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var headerCheck = function() {
      var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
      for (var i in x) {
        if(x[i] == "page=1")
          document.getElementsByClassName("headerContent")[0].style.display = "block";
       }
     }();
</script>
```

Similarly for your footer the code will look something like this:

```
<div class="footerContent" style="display: none">
    ...awesome footer html
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var footerCheck = function() {
       var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
       var currentPage = 1;
       for (var i in x) {
         var z=x[i].split('=',2);
         if(z[0] == "page")
           currentPage = unescape(z[1]);
         if(z[0] == "topage" && currentPage == unescape(z[1]))
           document.getElementsByClassName("footerContent")[0].style.display = "block";
        }
     }();
 </script>
```

Comment: This is great, a little modification and it will work to render different headers/footers for even/odd pages :)

Answer (score -1):

Add layout when rendering pdf

```
format.pdf do
  render :pdf => "my_pdf",
  :layout => 'pdf
end
```

views/layouts/pdf.haml

```
%html
  %head

  %body
    = render "layouts/header"
    = yield
    = render "layouts/footer"
```